# How to change reactor build order of Maven built projects

Tags: maven

How do i change the build order to allow [Object] to be built ahead of [EJB]?

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Car Booking Management Microsite Application
[INFO] Car Booking Management Microsite Application [EJB]
[INFO] Car Booking Management Microsite Application [Object]
[INFO] Car Booking Management Microsite Application [Web]
[INFO] Car Booking Management Microsite Application [DAO]
[INFO] Car Booking Management Microsite Application [EAR]
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant pom snippet as well as the command you are running? Also, is EJB dependant on Object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a dependency from EJB to Object.

But if that dependency doesn't exist, why do you care which one builds first?

Comment: Does it mean that build order is determined implicitly by Maven?

Comment: When inside a reactor, maven guarantees that projects are built in dependency order. Which makes sense as you want your downstream projects to be built using your upstream/library code rather than some potentially stale artifact obtained from who knows where.